# VS 2015 Hangs when I try to export the code analysis results

Tags: visual-studio-2015, static-analysis

I'm working on VS 2015 Enterprise, the problem is like follows: I executed the static code analysis tool on a project.  The error pane showed me near 100000 cases, but when I tried to export all of them into excel, VS 2015 hangs.  Please let me know how I can solve this problem, or how I can configure the program project file, in order to get the results of the static analysis tool into a file during compilation on VS2015 IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Could it come from this major .NET v4.6 GC bug?
[Gen2 free list changes in CLR 4.6 GC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maoni/archive/2015/08/12/gen2-free-list-changes-in-clr-4-6-gc.aspx)

See the *Lee Coward 6 Oct 2015 11:02 AM* answer in the blog post, it contains links to install the hotfix depending on your Windows version, and then retry after having installed the hot fix.

All the VS2015 hang issues I stumbled on (and there were many) got resolved with this trick.

Comment: Many thanks in advance for the answer.  Perhaps, do you have the title of the blog, in order to search the link?

Comment: Please forget the question above wrote, I was able to find the detail in the "Gen2 free list changes in ....." link.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you install the hotfix? Was this GC bug the cause of your problem?

Comment: I have a very big solution to compile.  During my review, MSBuild and FxCopCmd works faster than before with the hotfix; however, it seems that when the report is built in order to show in the error pane (VS2015 IDE), then the problem starts.  Perhaps do you know any hotfix or similar problem about it?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b7dc78de-1c3e-4f2c-b446-8c648d3cc6ea/visual-studio-2015-solution-tfs-build-with-code-analysis-takes-forever?forum=vsdebug  -> I was able to find this URL, it seems that the problem becomes from the code analyzer (fxcopcmd), because the symtom reported on that URL is like happens to me at the present time.

Comment: If the .NET v4.6 GC bug hotfix still results in slow analysis, this looks like indeed a cedo analysis issue

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround but to export code analysis results (or any other records) from the Error List window to a file (Excel/PDF/HTML), I would recommend [ErrorListManager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShemeerNS.ErrorListManager2ELM2) extension.

Since a significant time has passed since you wrote the question, I am posting this especially for case that others have similar issue.